# Java BufferedReader.readLine() returning null when reading file

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, null, bufferedreader

I need some help. This is my function:

```
public String[] getLines(String filename) {
    String[] returnVal = null;
    int i = 0;

    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(filename)));

        for(String line; (line = br.readLine()) != null; ) {
            // process the line.
            returnVal[i] = line;
            i++;
        }

        br.close();
    }
    // Catches any error conditions
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        debug.error("Unable to read file '"+filename+"'");
        debug.message(e.toString());
    }

    return returnVal;
}
```

which should return me String[] array with all the lines from a specified file. But I only get exception as return:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

and when I try to print the result it is null. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: `returnVal[i] ` -->`returnVal is null`. You have to *initialize* it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're setting the value to `null` explicitly:

```
String[] returnVal = null;
```

Since you don't know how many elements it'll contain, you should use an [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) instead<sup>*</sup>:

```
ArrayList<String> returnVal = new ArrayList<>();
```

<sup>* See the API to know what methods you should use to add objects to it</sup>

Comment: Thanks this helped me! But I wasn't setting the return to null explicitly I just initialized it. But now with the ArrayList it works great :)

Answer (score 1):

you have `returnVal` as null, `String[] returnVal = null;` and trying to write to it. If you know number of lines in advance, initialize it as `returnVal = new String [N_LINES];`, and change your loop condition to take into account number lines read. Otherwise you can use a list of strings and append to it as you read:

```
List<String> returnVal = new ArrayList<>();
...
while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    returnVal.add(line);
}
```

Not related to the original question but still: `br.close();` should be in `finally` and if you're using 1.7, you can benefit from [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html):

```
List<String> returnVal = new ArrayList<>();
try(BufferedReader br = 
    new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(filename)))) {
    while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        returnVal.add(line);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    debug.error("Unable to read file '"+filename+"'");
    debug.message(e.toString());
}
```